# Oracle subquery subtraction.

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to subtract a value from one table from a different table example if I have two tables like attached:

[image]

I want to update the numbers by subtractracting from QD in table QI so the new table will be

QI:
a  900
b  800
c  700

what's the best way to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there will only be 0 or 1 `qd` row per `col1` value:

```
update qi
set col2 = col2 - (select col2 from qd where qd.col1 = qi.col1)
where exists (select null from qd where qd.col1 = qi.col1);
```

The `where exists` clause is to prevent updating `qi` rows that have no `qd` counterpart.

Comment: What if the columns have different names? trying this I go something like subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: @bp01442 - use your real column names, obviously. If there are multiple rows in QD for each QI then you may just want an aggregate - in the subquery do `sum(c2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Better dont use subquery on this case. Use like this:

```
select I.COL1,
    (I.COL2 - D.COL2) as COL2
from TABLE_QI I
left join TABLE_QD D on D.COL1 = I.COL1;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08c639/2)

Comment: If there are any rows in QI that don't have matching rows in QD they'll be set to null; [`col1` 'd' in this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/946e9/1).

Comment: You also can't join in an update of course, at least without using a subquery *8-)